# useMutation does not work from react front end but works in apollo client with same variables Mutation.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to executate a mutation called createGroup, when i do it graphQl apolo clients it creates the group in firebase collection successfully but in the react frontend it does not work. When the create button is clicked in the appolo dev tools it shows as mutation started but nothing happens on firebase.

My mutation.js  from react-frontend

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const CREATE_GROUP = gql `
mutation CreateGroup(
  $name: String!,
  $description: String!,
  $leaders: [String]!,
  $members: [String]!,
  $notes: [NoteInput]!
) {
  createGroup(
    name: $name,
    description: $description,
    leaders: $leaders,
    members: $members,
    notes: $notes
  ) {
    id
    name
    description
    leaders {
      id
      name
    }
    members {
      id
      name
    }
    notes {
      id
      content
      createdBy {
        id
        name  
      }
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
`;
```

createGroup function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { CREATE_GROUP } from "../../GraphQL/Mutations"; 



const CreateGroup = () => {
  const [selectedLeaders, setSelectedLeaders] = useState([]);
  const [selectedMembers, setSelectedMembers] = useState([]);
  const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState("");
  const [groupDescription, setGroupDescription] = useState("");
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);


  const [availableLeaders, setAvailableLeaders] = useState(dataLeaders);
  const [availableMembers, setAvailableMembers] = useState(dataMembers);


  
  const [createGroup, {error}] = useMutation(CREATE_GROUP);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("just cliked me from submit")

      await createGroup({
        variables: {
          name: groupName,
          description: groupDescription,
          leaders: selectedLeaders,
          members: selectedMembers,
        },
      });
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
      }

      setSubmitted(true);
  };
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.REACT_APP_APOLLO_SERVER_URL,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
   
  </BrowserRouter>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I tried inspecting it with apolo dev tools  and i could see that the mutation starts and i have also tried  running the mutation in  apollo dev tools  but it keeps spining forever without returning anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally `await` the result of a mutation, instead I like to take advantage of its `onSuccess` and `onError` callbacks.

Example:

```
const [createGroup] = useMutation(CREATE_GROUP, {
  variables: {
    name: groupName,
    description: groupDescription,
    leaders: selectedLeaders,
    members: selectedMembers,
  },
  onCompleted: (data) => {
    setSubmitted(true);
    …do something with the data
  },
  onError: (error) => console.error(error),
})
```